# Configuring Webpack for React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to create a Reactjs project from scratch.  I've heard that it's easier to use `create-react-app`. I have also been told that the `standard industry practise` is to use webpack to bootstrap your React projects.

I have created my webpack config file like below:

```
const path = require('path');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config = {
    entry: SOURCE_DIR + "/app/app.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: "/\.js?/",
                include: SOURCE_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

and I have added the `build` and `build:prod` scripts for running in devt and production mode as so:

```
{
   "name": "basics",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "app.js",
   "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "webpack-dev-server",
      "build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && 
               webpack-dev-server --content-base: src/ --inline --hot",
   "build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [
     "React",
     "JavaScript",
     "Front End"
  ],
 "author": "MIT",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
     "react": "^16.2.0",
     "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
    },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
   }
}
```

When I run `npm start`, the app crashes and I get this error in console:

```
  Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
 object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, 
 exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, 
 unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?,
 unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, 
 wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, 
 strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
  -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && cp src/index.html 
dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base: src/ --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the basics@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

I think the error is in my build script where I'm doing the `copy` but I can't be sure as it's my first time with webpack.
Can someone help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using create-react-app for starting a new project. It gives you a solid webpack config right out of the gate. If you run into something you need support for that it doesn't, you can always eject at that point and add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `rules` instead of loaders. 
The information is there in the error. It tells you what are valid properties.

From the webpack docs https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

So for yours:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: "/\.js?/",
            include: SOURCE_DIR,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. What should I change here?

Comment: Instead of module -> loaders as you have at the moment, you want to do `module` -> `rules`. Think of it as if your module has a list of rules, and each rule has a test and can have loader/loaders

Comment: Thanks. It builds now. Can you tell me the importance of using webpack-cli -D?

Answer (score 0):

`Create-react-app` is the easiest option but if you really want to understand how everything is set up under the hood you might want to build a simple app using Webpack, Babel and React from scratch. that's what I did.

Or you could go through my tutorial to save some time. [Webpack, Babel, React, Redux, Apollo. From scratch to the production stack.](https://www.toni-develops.com/webpack/)